# Remove MVC directory names from URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to remove MVC directories from my URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ /application/controllers/main.php?page=$1 [L]
```

**So if i type in:** "localhost/project/page/dashboard"

**I want to visit:** "localhost/project/application/controllers/main.php?page=dashboard"

But i keep getting 404; where am i going wrong here?

Comment: Where is the location of this .htaccess? Are there other rules in this .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava its in the application directory, no i made a backup and just put in the above...

Comment: If you want `http://localhost/project/page/dashboard` then rule needs to be in `project` directory.

Comment: Can you put that as the answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `http://localhost/project/page/dashboard` then rule needs to be in `project` directory. You can use following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /project/

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ application/controllers/main.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```